# GWT behaves differently when url has gwt.codesvr

Tags: date, gwt

I created a simple GWT example using eclipse, I only added a method to GreetingService which is auto-generated.

```
Date greetServer2() ;
```

It's implemented like below:

```
    public Date greetServer2(){
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //
    String s = "2014/04/08";
    DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
    Date date=null;
    try {
        date = inputFormatter.parse(s);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return date;
}
```

On the client side I just show the date in a popup:

```
            greetingService.greetServer2(new AsyncCallback<Date>() {
                public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                    // Show the RPC error message to the user
                    ...
                }

                public void onSuccess(Date result) {
                    Window.alert(result.toString());
                }
            });
```

I run it via eclipse, the url generated by eclipse is:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/HelloGWT.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997
```

The popup window says "Tue Apr 08 00:00:00 CLST 2014"

But if I access without gwt.codesvr parameter:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8888/HelloGWT.html
```

The popup window says "Mon Apr 07 23:00:00 GMT-400 2014"

My GWT is 2.5.1, my JDK is 1.7.0_25.

Any clues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One result comes from a Java code, and the other one is produced by your browser. The difference is in the time zones. If you want consistent results, you should not use date.toString(), but display date using a `DateFormat`, and pass a time zone to it.

Remember that your users may be in different time zones, and they will all see a different "time" (and even a different date, like in your example) based on their browser settings, unless you specify a time zone in your code.

UPDATE:

There are different strategies for dealing with time zones. For example, you can save all dates as Long values (`date.getTime()`) for consistency. Then, you display it using a DateFormat and a time zone.

If you want to make sure that your date starts exactly at midnight in your selected time zone, make an adjustment before saving or using it. This is how I do it:

```
public static Long toMidnight(Long date, TimeZone timeZone) {
    return date - date % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000) +
            timeZone.getOffset(new Date(date)) * 60 * 1000;
}
```

Comment: Hi, the client(browser) and server are both on the same laptop. And the timezone i'm using is (UTC-04:00 Santiago). Actually, the reason I'm writing this example is because I do run into some timezone problem, and i try to debug it, but gwt app behaves differently between normally run and debug mode, and this causes lots of confusions.

Comment: Then use DateFormat and pass the time zone. Using `date.toString()` will not help you find a problem - you have the same date, just displayed differently by Java and JavaScript.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I use this to format the date: ateTimeFormat f = DateTimeFormat.getFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G HH:mm:ss vvvv");  TimeZoneConstants t = (TimeZoneConstants)   GWT.create(TimeZoneConstants.class);  TimeZone tz = TimeZone.createTimeZone(t.americaSantiago());  Window.alert(f.format(result, tz));  now both scenarios return same date string, but it's 2014-04-07 23:00:00, what should i do if I need it to be 2014-04-08 00:00:00?

Comment: `One result comes from a plugin that tries to emulate JavaScript behavior`: actually, no. In DevMode, Java code runs in Java, so you're directly using the `java.util.Date#toString()`. In prod mode, you run the _emulated_ version from GWT. See http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasicsCompatibility.html (which is a bit out of date BTW)